# Preventing duplication before it occurs in setState arrays

Tags: arrays, reactjs

An onClick function called 'addItem' that adds items to a certain array called 'cart' is being fired whenever a button called 'add' is clicked. I'd like to implement a mechanism that prevents duplication in the cart array but owing to the asynchronous nature of setState, such a mechanism would not work inside the addItem function as I have it. And I can't seem to perceive a way forward. Any directions will be highly appreciated.

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

//Function that enables addition of products to the cart array
const addItem =  (prod, index) => {
//conditional statement aimed at preventing duplication in the
//cart array; but doesn't work as intended
    if (cart.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        alert("Already added")
      }else{
        setCart([...cart, prod]);
      }
  };

//button that adds items parsed as 'prod' to the cart 
//array by calling the addItem function 
  <button 
  className="itemButton" 
  onClick={() => {
    addItem(prod, index);
  }}
  >
  Add
  </button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you want to prevent adding the same `prod` twice you need to check the cart for whatever `prod` is, not whether or not there's an array entry at `index`.

Comment: I want to prevent adding the same `prod` twice. The problem is that within the `addItem` function,  the clicked `prod` does not reflect in the cart until after the next click. In that if I were to `console.log` the `cart` right after `setCart` an empty array would be returned following a single click; the clicked `prod` doesn't immediately reflect in the `cart` .

Comment: If you `console.log(cart)` immediately after `setCart` you're seeing the current `cart` state. Setting state is async in the sense that it updates state at an arbitrary time in the future (not in the sense it can be `await`ed).

Answer (score 0):

As I right understood you want something like this ?

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([]);
    // Function that enables addition of products to the cart array
    const addItem = (prod, index) => {
        // conditional statement aimed at preventing duplication in the
        // cart array; but doesn't work as intended
        setCart((prevState) => {
            if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(prevState, index)) {
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    ...{ prod },
                };
            }
            return prevState;
        });
    };
    return (
        <>
            Cart is : {JSON.stringify(cart)}
            <button
                type="button"
                className="itemButton"
                onClick={() => {
                    addItem({ test: 'randomKey' }, 'test');
                }}
            >
                Add
            </button>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```